# got stuck in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count the maximum number of messages that a single user has sent and received from another single user. I am not getting understand how to achieve this.

```
Example for 3 messages exchanged:
[1] John(1472) msg Jane
    Jane msg John(1472)
[2] John(1472) msg Jane
    Jane msg John(1472)
[3] John(1472) msg Jane
```

OR

```
[1] John(1472) msg Jane
    Jane msg John(1472)
[2] John(1472) msg Jane
    Jane msg John(1472)
[3] John(1472) msg Jane
    Jane msg John(1472)
```

OR

```
[1] John(1472) msg Jane
    John(1472) msg Jane
    John(1472) msg Jane
    Jane msg John(1472)
[2] John(1472) msg Jane
    John(1472) msg Jane
    Jane msg John(1472)
    Jane msg John(1472)
[3] John(1472) msg Jane
    Jane msg John(1472)
```

All above examples will give 3 messages exchanged between these two users. My Table structure is like this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f84f17/1

Everytime a user sends a message to another user, we are inserting two rows in mailbox table with different senderid, receiverid, owner and folder(inbox/sent).

Comment: Why you are using such complex structure.Just have 4 columns like senderId,receiverId,message,status 
Where status will represent that whether message is successfully sent by or received by user.

Comment: Table structure is not created by me. This is already made project and I have to generate reports for it. :) The site is using osDate framework.

Comment: Then run the query like WHERE senderid = '1472' AND recipientid = '338'

Comment: senderid is fixed but the recipientid is not fixed. For example, I have to check how many messages exchanged between 1472 and other users?

Comment: Then use  WHERE senderid = '1472' GROUP BY recipientid

Comment: Thanks for the answer sunil. I have just edited the question and added one more example.  GROUP BY will not work in the above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select largest number of messages exchanged between a user and any other user you can group by peer, order by count, and pick the first result:

```
SELECT count(*), if(owner=senderid, recipientid, senderid) as peer FROM mailbox
WHERE owner = 1472
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY 1 desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the anser @alex. But it will not work for 3rd example

Comment: Probably not. Could you elaborate how do you group messages in the 3rd example. Ideally, put some sample data to sqlfiddle.